# Mapcar and assoc

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I would like to do:

```
(mapcar #'assoc '(a s) '((a . b) (c . d) (s . f)))
```

and have it return

```
((A . B) (S . F))
```

Which seems pretty reasonable, considering `(assoc 'a '((a . b) (c . d) (s . f)))` returns `(A . B)` and `(assoc 's '((a . b) (c . d) (s . f)))` returns `(S . F)`. But alas it does not work:

```
*** - ASSOC: A is not a list
The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When used with two lists, `mapcar` applies the function pair-wise to the lists (and with three lists it applies them triple-wise etc.). So

```
(mapcar #'assoc '(a s) '((a . b) (c . d) (s . f)))
```

is the same as

```
( (assoc 'a (a . b)) (assoc 's (c . d)) )
```

(when used with lists of different length, `mapcar` uses the size of the smallest list). To get what you want, you should do:

```
(mapcar (lambda (x) (assoc x '((a . b) (c . d) (s . f)))) '(a s))
```

Answer (score 5):

We need another list level. The second argument should be a list of assoc lists.

```
CL-USER >  (mapcar #'assoc '(a s) '(((a . b) (c . d) (s . f))))

((A . B))
```

But the second argument is only one element long. Now we can use a trick and make it a circular list:

```
CL-USER > (mapcar #'assoc '(a s) '#1=(((A . B) (C . D) (S . F)) . #1#))

((A . B) (S . F))
```

If we construct a circular list for the second argument, then it works.

As a function:

```
(defun circular (list)
  (if (null list)
      list
    (setf (cdr (last list)) list)))

CL-USER > (mapcar #'assoc '(a s) (circular '(((a . b) (c . d) (s . f)))))

((A . B) (S . F))
```